# Android - Using generics to have 1 RxJava retrofit call returning various types using the same interface

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, retrofit2

I'm playing around with Generics for the first time to clean up some repeated code I have around retrofit calls.

I was able to make a generic retrofit adapter, so my providers didn't have to each have a unique creator, which was really awesome and exciting.

```
private fun <T> create(service: Class<T>, baseUrl: String): T {
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .build()

        return retrofit.create(service)
    }
```

Now I'm trying to do a generic network call, but I'm not able to figure it out, and wondering if it's even possible given how Retrofit works?

I have 5 services like below right now, all hitting different APIs.  Each one has a different end point, but all accept 1 parameter and return their object which is slightly different for each API call.

```
interface ServiceA {
    @GET("v2/ticker")
    fun getCurrentTradingInfo(@Query("book") orderBook: String): Observable<CurrentTradingInfo>
}
```

---

All the response objects implement an interface to normalize the response data so I can display it later

---

```
data class CurrentTradingInfo(val mid: String,
                              val bid: String,
                              val ask: String,
                              val last_price: String,
                              val low: String,
                              val high: String,
                              val volume: String,
                              val timestamp: String) : normalizedData {

    override fun lastPrice(): String {
        return last_price
    }

    override fun timeStamp(): String {
        return timestamp
    }
}
```

---

Currently, I have a network call for each service like below

```
 val disposable = service.getCurrentTradingInfo(ticker.ticker)
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .repeatWhen { result -> result.delay(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS) }
                    .retryWhen { error -> error.delay(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS) }
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .subscribe({ result ->

                        val tradingInfo = TradingInfo(result.lastPrice(), result.timeStamp())
                        networkDataUpdate.updateData(ticker, tradingInfo)
                        callback.updateUi(ticker)

                    }, { error ->
                        error.printStackTrace()
                    })
```

From my little knowledge of generics, it seems like I should be able to pass in a generic service and handle as many different API ends points using this one RxJava call?  I don't know how to access each services getCurrentTradingInfo method though, and from what I do read, I'm doubting if it's possible using retrofit interfaces?

I'm not necessarily looking for a complete answer if it's possible (although an explanation would be nice) but I'm wondering if it's even possible to do in this specific scenario?  I don't want to keep wasting my time if it's not even possible.

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to come up with the below which is a lot better than what I had before.  I still can't figure out a way around the interface so there's a little duplication for each API in each xxxRepository class but a lot less.

```
interface QuadrigaService {
    @GET("v2/ticker")
    fun getCurrentTradingInfo(@Query("book") query: String): Observable<CurrentTradingInfo>
}
```

---

```
class QuadrigaRepository(private val service: QuadrigaService) : BaseExchangeRepository() {
    override fun feedType(): String {
        return CryptoPairs.QUADRIGA_BTC_CAD.exchange
    }

    override fun startFeed(tickers: List<CryptoPairs>, presenterCallback: NetworkCompletionCallback, networkDataUpdate: NetworkDataUpdate) {
        clearDisposables()

        tickers.forEach { ticker ->
            startFeed(service.getCurrentTradingInfo(ticker.ticker),
                    ticker, presenterCallback, networkDataUpdate)
        }
    }
}
```

---

And the base class using generics

---

```
abstract class BaseExchangeRepository : Exchange {

    var disposables: CompositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()

    fun clearDisposables() {
        if (disposables.size() != 0) {
            disposables.clear()
        }
    }

    fun <T> startFeed(observable: Observable<T>, ticker: CryptoPairs, presenterCallback: NetworkCompletionCallback, networkDataUpdate: NetworkDataUpdate) {
        val disposable = observable.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .repeatWhen { result -> result.delay(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS) }
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe({ result ->
                    result as NormalizedTickerData

                    Log.d("Result", ticker.toString() + "last price is ${result.lastPrice()}")

                    val tradingInfo = TradingInfo(result.lastPrice(), result.timeStamp())
                    networkDataUpdate.updateData(ticker, tradingInfo)
                    presenterCallback.updateUi(ticker)

                }, { error ->
                    error.printStackTrace()
                })

        disposables.add(disposable)
    }

    override fun stopFeed() {
        disposables.clear()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using `compose()`:

```
 val disposable = service.getCurrentTradingInfo(ticker.ticker)
                         .compose(displayOnTicker(ticker))
                         .subscribe();
```

Then just in your `displayOnTicker(Source)` (apologies for the Java-isms):

```
 return source -> source
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .repeatWhen { result -> result.delay(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS) }
                .retryWhen { error -> error.delay(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS) }
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .doOnNext({ result ->
                    val tradingInfo = TradingInfo(result.lastPrice(), result.timeStamp())
                    networkDataUpdate.updateData(ticker, tradingInfo)
                    callback.updateUi(ticker)
                })
                // add .doOnError / .onErrorResumeNext as desired
                ;
```

This allows you to

- be completely independent from a class hierarchy
- reuse the same displayOnTicker in other location
- maybe place the displayOnTicker in a mixin?